# Installing ubuntu 16.04 studio on a samsung 30034c 300e5c 300e7c

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-7, samsung, ubuntu-studio

I have a samsung 30034c 300e5c 300e7c 64 bits with a BIOS: Phoenix SC-T v2.2.

Recently i install Ubuntu Studio 16.04 on an external hard drive, i was able to open the BIOS with f2 and every time i want to use ubuntu i hit the f10 button without a problem, everything is smooth and nice, and i'm thrill with this system, but now i want to install it on my hard drive and replace windows 7 that is currently on the computer hard drive.

The problem begins when this laptop was purchase, windows 8 was its operating system and then it was replaced with win 7 (not without a fight), and i've reading about replacing win 7 with ubuntu and i found out that some Samsung computers have problems with ubuntu, some odds things happend with the BIOS and the UEFI, making the computer useless.
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/01/31/ubuntu_uefi_bricking_samsung_laptops/

...... so, thats it, i want to install ubuntu studio but im not sure about the UEFI problem, anyone can help me about the UEFI doubts and if maybe someone has experience with configurating samsung computers it would be great...

Answer (score 1):

It maybe something related to UEFI or legacy BIOS.

Since your system was Windows 8, it is possibly a UEFI, but you'd better enter your BIOS to make sure of it.

In my case, it is shown in BIOS mode, and it is LEGACY now.

[image: BIOS]

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, your model of laptop is not **reported** as affected, so it could be fine, or it could not. From my experience, I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 10 on my Samsung UEFI BIOS laptop smoothly, but I understand if you don't want to risk your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

This model is affected by the UEFI bug.

Yo make sure you do not brick the laptop disable UEFI boot in BIOS.

Then you can install Ubuntu fine. I have one of these laptops.